# App stopped working as it should for devices on lollipop and below

Tags: android

I have an android app on GooglePlay.  The app was working very fine for all devices before last friday(30th september 2016). After last friday my app stucks at my splash screen for some phone. I have not updated the app for a year in googleplay.

I came to know that the app is working  fine with devices Marshmellow and above. The phones with Lollipop and below stuck at splash screen. I do have a network call script  in splash screen.

What could be the problem and solution for this?

Here is a code for https networkcall using AsycHttpClient.  On some devices onSuccess is invoked which sends to another activity . While on some devices onFailure is invoked causing it to stuck at splash screen with Request time out dialog.
I get some ssl erros whenever it stucks at splashScreen.

```
AppData.defaultProfileImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.icon_profile);
                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams("grant_type",
                        "refresh_token");
                params.put("refresh_token", AppData.refreshToken);
                params.put("client_id", AppData.clientId);
                params.put("client_secret", AppData.clientSecret);
                client.setTimeout(10000);
                client.post(AppData.urlRefreshToken, params,
                        new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                            boolean nextActivity = false;

                            @Override
                            public void onStart() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // Log.d("started auth", "yep");
                                // sudhirDai();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String content) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // Log.d("auth success", "yep");
                                nextActivity = parseJsonForAccessTokens(content);
                                if (nextActivity) {
                                    new GetProfileData().execute();
                                }
                                if (AppData.showRegisterActivity) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                            RegisterLocationActivity.class));
                                    // new LoadCommunityTask().execute();
                                    finish();
                                } else if (nextActivity) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            MainActivity.this,
                                            MainActivityTwo.class);
                                    // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    if (fromNotification != null) {
                                        // Log.d("mainactivity",
                                        // "notification intent extra kept");
                                        intent.putExtra("notification_type",
                                                fromNotification);
                                        intent.putExtra("notification_id",
                                                notificationId);
                                    }
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    new LoadCommunityTask().execute();
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                            LoginActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable error,
                                    String content) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // Log.d("failure", "failure");
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                // Log.d("content", content + " is content");
                                StaticFunctions.createCustomDialog(
                                        MainActivity.this, "Request time out.");
                            }
                        });
```

Here is log:

```
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <www.rugbyworldirectory.com> != <*.firstfind.nl> OR <*.firstfind.nl> OR <firstfind.nl>
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:190)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:59)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:119)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:100)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:393)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:170)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:369)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:74)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:91)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:54)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-05 16:10:53.130 15037-15076/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-05 16:10:53.140 15037-15037/? W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <www.rugbyworldirectory.com> != <*.firstfind.nl> OR
```

Comment: Well, I never used SSL but you should check if your SSL certificate is still valid. Doesn't explain the limit problem but this is what I read from the exception ;)